# WSO2 compressing SAML over POST binding

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to register WSO2 as a identity provider for PingOne. After configuring both PingOne and WSO2 PingOne would complain about not being able to process WSO2's SAML response.

After working with Ping technical support, we discovered that the WSO2 compresses SAML when sending it using the SAML POST binding which is a violation of the SAML specification.

I dug around on the web and it seems that the WSO2 team is already aware of this issue and it is fixed in version 4.1.1. Unfortunately, there does not seem to be a 4.1.1 download on the WSO2 page.

If the WSO2 support team monitoring stack overflow could please recommend how I should proceed to work around this issue I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

There was such issue and it has been fixed in 4.5.0.  Actually, there was a plan to release 4.1.1.  But due to new features, finally it has been renamed as 4.5.0. Please download 4.5.0 from official website http://wso2.com/products/identity-server and try out it.